# CSS hover animation - Target last div in list

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hello :) I have added a little underline animation to my bootstrap menu here: http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net so on hover, it draws the underline from the centre. Heres the CSS I used to achieve this:

```
/* ---------------------- Animated hover --------------------- */

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FEB700;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* ----------------------------------- */
```

As you will see, the last item in the list, Control Panel, I have added a padlock icon before it using the: `li:last-of-type:before` selector like so:

```
.navbar li:last-of-type:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\F023";
  float: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
}


.navbar li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Because of this icon, the underline animation is not centres to the button, and appears to stick out more on the right.

I can fix this by adjusting the `width:;` and the `left:;` but this of course effects all other underlines in the menu.

Im trying to combine the two I guess so I can target the last `.nav-link` item and apply a slightly different set of rules to the `width:;` and the `left:;` selectors... But I'm stuck and everything I have tried doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone shed some light on the situation? is this correct or is there a better way to approach this? Thanks for reading!:)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does this mean you want the code thats outputted for the NAV too?

Comment: You guarantee that link you gave will demonstrate your issue in 2 years, too? And in 5 years? Your question will still be here then.

Comment: Can't you add the icon without using the `:before` selector? As adding the icon in the HTML. That way you don't need to fiddle with the margin and it would just be text content like the text in the nav.

Comment: See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thanks all for the vote downs... But thank you @connexo for actually explaining it to me - I now understand and will see if I can repose the question.

Comment: That's a good idea @Brainfeeder I will have a look and see how I can do this - Do you know a way off the top of your head? I will search though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Font Awesome icons in HTML without the CSS magic like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lock"></i>
```

Some people use the `<em>` tag or something else, I like `<i>` more ...

> You can place Font Awesome icons just about anywhere using the CSS Prefix fa and the icon's name. Font Awesome is designed to be used with inline elements (we like the `<i>` tag for brevity, but using a `<span>` is more semantically correct). 
>   [See Font Awesome documentation](http://fontawesome.io/examples/).

Comment: Perfect thank you - I wasnt sure about this as the nav is dynamically generated, but just adding the <i> version in front of the button name in wordpress does the trick! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

While messing around with the code I found that this

```
.navbar li:last-of-type a:before {
  left: -6px;
}
```

**edit**

```
li#menu-item-750 a:before {
    left: -6px;
}
```

Seemed to achieve a fix to your issue, as it's targeting the `before` on the last `li` entry, it should do the job

Comment: Thanks @Andy - But this doesnt seem to work, ive copied it exactly but to no effect - Thanks for looking :)

Comment: @ShaunTaylor see my update, I used the specific selector that wordpress kicks out for that item

Comment: Be aware of WordPress cache, if changes are not visible after uploading, try clearing browser cache.

Comment: Thanks again @Andy, Ive gone with the Answer above as it seems less of a workaround and more of a complete solution.

Comment: Yeah I agree @ShaunTaylor, a much better implementation :)